# Updating attached entries in Entity Framework 6 without modifying foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Say you have the following model,

```cs
class Car {
   int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual List<Passenger> Passengers { get; set; }
}

class Passenger {
   int Id { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("Car")]
   int CarId { get; set; }
   public virtual Car Car { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And you're modifying the Name without having Entity Framework load the model, just knowing the ID, and not knowing the Car - in my case also by having auto-loading & verification disabled, since I was working on a huge data-set.

Doing something as follows runs into an error

```cs
CarDbContext context = new CarDbContext(); // subclass of DbContext
Passenger passenger = new Passenger();
passenger.Id = 1; // this was sent to you from heaven, or from a URL, or whatever
passenger.Name = "Steve"; // this is your updated variable
context.Attach(passenger);
DbEntityEntry<Passenger> dbEntry = context.Entry(passenger);
dbEntry.Property(e => e.Name).IsModified = true; // we changed the Name, but...
dbEntry.Property(e => e.CarId).IsModified = false; // we didn't change the Foreign Key
context.SaveChanges(); // will still yield an error!
```

The error there is: "Unable to determine the principal end of the relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To circumvent the error, you have to set the CarId to a value, but you can still mark it as not modified. The changes you seem to be making don't propagate to your data store.

```cs
// [...] from previous sample
passenger.CarId = 9001; // it's over 9000
dbEntry.Property(e => e.CarId).IsModified = false; // we didn't change the Foreign Key
context.SaveChanges(); // works!
```